# Redis Sentinel: Master name in notifications

Tags: notifications, redis, redis-sentinel

When Redis Sentinel notifies about events, it does not provide the name of the Redis master.

An excerpt from the config:

```
# sentinel notification-script <master-name> <script-path>
#
# Call the specified notification script for any sentinel event that is
# generated in the WARNING level (for instance -sdown, -odown, and so forth).
# This script should notify the system administrator via email, SMS, or any
# other messaging system, that there is something wrong with the monitored
# Redis systems.
#
# The script is called with just two arguments: the first is the event type
# and the second the event description.
```

So there only is the event type (e.g. `+odown`) and the event description, which in case of `+odown` simply is `master`. Somehow I feel this is lacking important information. We do not only want to notify users that something has changed but **where** it changed.

You can't register a script with additional parameters, e.g.

```
sentinel notification-script <master-name> "<script-path> <master-name>"
```

Redis will use the value as a whole and check if it exists and is executable.

We solved this by creating small wrapper scripts, one for each master instance.

```
$ cat /some/path/notify-master42.sh
#!/bin/sh
/some/path/notify.sh master42 $1 $2
```

This wrapper script then is attached to the master:

```
sentinel notification-script <master-name> notification-script /some/path/notify-<master-name>.sh
```

That's a bit uncomfortable but not too bad, as long as you have a fixed number of masters and do not create them on the fly over the net.

You can register new masters by simply interacting with the sentinel over the net. (`redis-cli -h <host> -p <port> sentinel whatever...`) But creating those wrapper scripts is more complicated. Not that this is impossible, but it feels like jumping through burning hoops for nothing.

Is there a way to notify including master names:

- without patching redis
- without having wrapper scripts

?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do it by using the correct event.

"So there only is the event type (e.g. +odown) and the event description, which in case of +odown simply is master. Somehow I feel this is lacking important information. We do not only want to notify users that something has changed but where it changed."

In the case of +odown there *is* no other information to be had. All **+odown** means is the master server went down. At this point nothing else has happened. If you want to update something based on the *fail-over* (which happens *after* **+odown**) you need to look at the appropriate event: **switch-master**. The **switch-master** event is what happens when a failover completes.

Taken directly from the [documentation](http://redis.io/topics/sentinel):

> **switch-master** `<master name> <oldip> <oldport> <newip> <newport>` -- The master new IP and address is the specified one after a configuration change. **This is the message most external users are interested in.**

So have your script look for and act upon the switch-master event to get the information about what changed. No more burning hoops to jump through.

Comment: I do not only want to notify when failover happens. I am notifying also on +/- odwon/sdown.

Comment: i cannot get the notification on +/- odown/sdown as described,neither! i can just get the notification '+new-epoch xx'!